# Have a 'for' loop remove class name from element if it contains that name, otherwise, do nothing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of buttons, and when one is clicked, that button's class name will change to move it across the screen and bring in a `'back'` button whose purpose, when clicked, is to return the previously clicked button to the line of other buttons and then the back button hides again. Everything works except the button that was clicked doesn't return to the list when the user clicks the `'back'` button. I'm assuming it's something wrong with the `for` loop, but it makes sense in my head. Here is the script:

```
//Variables
var back = document.getElementById('back');
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var i;

/*moves button that was clicked to center of page
and changes class of hidden back button to make it show*/
//works fine 

function moveButton(e) {
'use strict';
var target = e.target;
target.classList.add('second_pos');
back.className = 'back';
}

//removes back button and returns active button to top
//Does remove back button but loop doesn't work on other button

function goBack() {
back.className = 'back_hidden';
 for ( i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  if (button[i].classList.contains('second_pos')) {
    button[i].classList.remove('second_pos');
  } else {
   return;
  }
 }
}

//Event Listener for main buttons

for (i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  button[i].addEventListener('click', moveButton, false);
}

// Event listener for back button

 back.addEventListener('click', goBack, false);
```

and here is the css

```
.demo_space {
  display:table;
  position:relative;
  height:100vh;
  width:90%;
  margin:0 auto;
  ul {
    display:table-cell;
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;

    li {
      display:inline-block;
    }
  }
}

.first_pos {
  float:left;
  font-size:2em;
  padding:1em;
  color:$green;
}

.second_pos {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:50%;
  left:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `else` part, as it breaks the loop.

```js
for (i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  if (button[i].classList.contains('second_pos')) {
    button[i].classList.remove('second_pos');
  } // else {
    // return;
  // }
}
```

Comment: @DJO What happens when you try it? What doesn't work?

Comment: When I click the back button, it's class changes, but the class on the previously targeted button doesn't change and just stays in the center of the page. I figured the loop would check each button for the .second_pos class, and then remove it if it was there or else move on to the next button. However, it doesn't seem to me changing the element as all.

Comment: @DJO Can you make a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) and show the steps to repro?

Comment: @DJO Yup.. I was able to see something is happening... What's supposed to happen, and what shouldn't happen?

Comment: @DJO Since you are using jQuery, you don't need to do so much code. A lot can be avoided. I really need to know what you are expecting so that I can guide you!

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. It's moving the button down the page when it's clicked, but when I click the back button that slides in from the outside, it doesn't return the previously clicked button to the top. I'm using that loop to try and remove the .second_pos class so it returns to the original position. And I loaded jQuery because I was going to try it, but I feel like I should get better at JS first, so this is practice, which isn't going so well haha

Comment: @DJO Yea yea, I understand you are trying out something. Okay, tell me one thing. Let me try to recreate the whole stuff. What I would require from you is, I wanna know what you are totally trying to achieve, don't talk about the current code, just tell me in plain language, so that I will try rebuilding it using just jQuery and comment the whole thing so that you'll be able to understand as well.

Comment: Wow, you're the bomb. I want to have the three buttons up top, and when one is clicked, have it move to a central position on the page and a back button move onto the page. When the back button is clicked, the button in the center would return to the top of the page with the other buttons. After figuring out how to do this, I wanted to have the buttons that weren't clicked disappear, and then reappear once the back button is hit and the central button rejoins them, but don't worry about that part. Again, thank you so much!